# How do I format HTML, removing unwanted line breaks?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, line-breaks, code-formatting

I would like to do something like this:

```
<div class="show_details_block">
  <% if @model.details.length > 0 then %>
    <%= h(@model.details) %>
  <% else %>
    "No details available"
  <% end %>
</div>
```

However, this adds unwanted line breaks to my HTML source. I would prefer to avoid writing it inline like this:

```
<div class="show_details_block"><% if @task.details.length <= 0 then %>"No details available"<% else %><%= h(@task.details) %><% end %></div>
```

Can I maintain my code formatting/styling without having to face the consequences of unwanted line breaks?

Haml counterpart:

```
.show_details_block
  - if @model.details.length > 0 then
    = h(@model.details)
  - else
    No details provided..
```

Comment: [Haml](http://haml.info/) :P

Comment: Actually I think the inline style is ugly. Generally a line of code should not be longer than 80 or so.

Comment: @rynah `haml` is seemingly just as bad, if not worse. I do appreciate the speed increase, however, it does not solve my added line break problem. It actually makes it worse.

Comment: @RileyE,  HAML has a lot of advantages, one of which is it can generate "pretty" HTML during development or "ugly" in production, which is stripped of unnecessary whitespace, depending on the setting of the "[`Haml::Options[:ugly]`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html)" flag. That flag would fix the problem for you, and, at the same time, reduce the amount of useless bytes you send to the browser.

Comment: @theTinMan I've added the flag `Haml::Options.defaults[:ugly] = :true` to my haml.rb file, but the whitespace seems to still be there. I'm really not sure what to do about it other than switch back to erb and remove all formatting.

Comment: If the whitespace is still there and the HTML is still indented/"prettified", then that either got reset or didn't get run.

Comment: @theTinMan It's not indented or really prettified, but it still has the extra line break. I've posted my relevant `haml`.

Comment: Is it maybe part of `@model.details`?

Comment: @rynah If I write it in a single line, the break lines disappear.

Answer (score 2):

ERB allows you to use `<%-` and `-%>` around your code interpolation.  These forms suppress the line-breaks before or after the start/end interpolation marks.  See the description of [trim-mode in `ERB::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new)

Comment: Is there a way to also prevent the html breaks?